# Creating NSMenuItems programmatically in MonoMac

Tags: c#, macos, mono, nsmenuitem, monomac

I'm trying to programmatically add a menu to my MonoMac application. I've opened up the MainMenu.xib and removed all `NSMenuItem` from the MainMenu control.

I'm adding the following code into my `FinishedLaunching` override:

```
var fileMenuItem = new NSMenuItem("File");
var fileMenu = new NSMenu();

var fileNew = new NSMenuItem("New");
var fileOpen = new NSMenuItem("Open");
var fileSave = new NSMenuItem("Save");

fileMenu.AddItem(fileNew);
fileMenu.AddItem(fileOpen);
fileMenu.AddItem(fileSave);

fileMenuItem.Menu = fileMenu;

NSApplication.SharedApplication.MainMenu.AddItem(fileMenuItem);
```

But it's not doing anything.

When I add the code to `MainWindowController.Initialize()`, I get an assertion failure "item to be inserted into menu already is in another menu"

I was porting the code found in this SO answer: [Creating NSMenu with NSMenuItems in it, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706806/creating-nsmenu-with-nsmenuitems-in-it-programmatically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I had to do the following:

```
fileMenuItem.Submenu = fileMenu;
```

The Submenu property of the NSMenuItem should have been set to the actual menu instead of the Menu property.

Comment: this works, though you should also set title of fileMenu.title = "Someting" if it is not first item (that always have name of application)