# How to create a menu programmatically without any interface builder files in MacOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I found the question [Creating NSMenu with NSMenuItems in it, programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6706806/16217248) but failed to get the solution to work in my application. I tried combining the code from the question and accepted answer to get the following:

```
NSMenu *fileMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"File"];
NSMenuItem *newMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
NSMenuItem *openMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Open" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
NSMenuItem *saveMenu = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" action:NULL keyEquivalent:@""];
[fileMenu addItem: newMenu];
[fileMenu addItem: openMenu];
[fileMenu addItem: saveMenu];
NSMenuItem *fileMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];
[fileMenuItem setSubmenu: fileMenu];
[[NSApp mainMenu] addItem: fileMenuItem];
[fileMenuItem release];
```

No `File` menu is created. Placement of the above code before or after the other code in the main function is inconsequential. I also tried placing in `applicationDidFinishLauching` to no avail. Why does the above code fail to function, and how can I give my application a menu without using any XIB or Storyboard files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For Objective-C, the nsmenuitem nsmenu menu bar does not display problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507113/for-objective-c-the-nsmenuitem-nsmenu-menu-bar-does-not-display-problems)

Comment: @Willeke The linked answer simply provides an allegedly functioning example. I would prefer an answer that clearly explains where my code has it wrong and what the solution is and *why* the solution works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to add a menubar in order to get your code to run.  Could also use addItemWithTitle: and save a few lines of code. If you don't hook up each menuItem to a method they will be grayed out.  -buildMenu is usually called from -applicationWillFinishLaunching: in AppDelegate.

```
- (void) menuAction: (id)sender {
 NSLog(@"%@", sender);
}

- (void) buildMenu {
// **** Menu Bar **** //
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
// **** App Menu **** //
 NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 [appMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
 [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
// **** File Menu **** //
 NSMenuItem *fileMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 NSMenu *fileMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"File"];
 [fileMenu addItemWithTitle:@"New" action:@selector(menuAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
 [fileMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Open" action:@selector(menuAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
 [fileMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Save" action:@selector(menuAction:) keyEquivalent:@""];
 [fileMenuItem setSubmenu: fileMenu];
 [menubar addItem: fileMenuItem];
}
```

Comment: Please don't copy answers, mark the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: No, I was about to downvote but I didn't. Please don't post a lot of irrelevant code.

Comment: If I need to create a main menu first presumably because one does not automatically exist, then why does `[[NSApp mainMenu] addItem: fileMenuItem]` not crash the program for a `nil` reference?

Comment: The code posted doesn't work because [NSApp mainMenu] is null; you have no menubar.  True, it doesn't crash, but it also won't work until you create a menubar.  I don't know why it doesn't crash (unlike another language I work with) but lucky for us it doesn't.  Robust os I guess.

Comment: @apodidae But if `[NSApp mainMenu] == NULL` why does calling `addItem` method not even crash? In Objective-C you can call a method on a `NULL` object and silently fail instead of crashing?

Comment: I think that's right.  When things don't work as expected in objc you need to start checking values; often an obj is null and that's why it doesn't work.  The app doesn't always crash, it just silently fails; are you used to working in Java?

Comment: @apodidae Java (Null Pointer Exception), plain C (Segmentation Fault), Swift (Crash from unexpectedly finding NULL in an optional), most languages in fact, will yield some sort of error/crash upon attempting to use a NULL value/pointer in any meaningful way. The fact that Objective-C objects do not do this is confusing.

Comment: I don't think you'll get into too much trouble if you try to use something you never alloc/inited in the first place; if you want to get into trouble, try releasing fileMenuItem before you add it to the menubar, ie move [fileMenuItem release]; up one line of code. Should cause a segmentation fault. Trying to reuse an obj that has been alloc/inited and then released is the trouble maker.